# Accessing branches of a remote repository

Tags: git

Trying to perform a pull from a remote repository, however the relevant code is located in a branch that is not master. I have pulled the main branch of the repository to the local branch, however the intended branch is still eluding me, and this is to inquire as to the command to point the git client toward the intended branch. The commands so far are :

```
git init
git echo > file
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git remote add remoteRepository <remote address>
git pull remoteRepository master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone [url to repository] directoryname
cd directoryname
git checkout thebranchname
```

The "git clone" will sync the repository.  If you do a "git branch" after doing the initial "git clone", it may not reveal the other branches. (Perhaps that's a bug?)  Rest assured, as soon as you type the "git checkout" command, it magically switches you to the expected branch.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. `git init` is for creating a new repository.

If you want a copy of an *existing* repository, you need to clone it:

```
git clone <remote address>
```

At which point you will simply be able to check out the branch:

```
git checkout <branch>
```

If no local branch exists, and Git finds a remote branch with the name you specified, Git will create a local branch tracking the remote one, and switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

Git fetch and then git checkout -t remoteRepository/branch